# Python Imports Convention

Tags: python

I've noticed in Python code it's usually preferred to import explicitly the parts of a module you need, eg

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
```

However, I've noticed that this doesn't seem to be the case for Python standard library modules, where I'd typically see, eg:

```
import os
import sys

something = os.path.join('home', 'ludo')
other = sys.argv('dunno')
```

instead of

```
from os.path import join
from sys import argv

something = join('home', 'ludo')
other = argv('dunno')
```

Is there any reasoning or documented convention for this?

Comment: I would generally go by some combination of: number of things needed from each `import` (I wouldn't go over four or five in `from foo import bar, baz, ...`); length of module name (i.e. how many characters do I have to type out each time, although aliasing like `import tkinter as tk` helps there); number of times I plan to call each thing I'm importing; etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [holy style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) is pretty loose regarding this subject:

> When importing a class from a class-containing module, it's usually
>   okay to spell this:
>
> ```
> from myclass import MyClass
> from foo.bar.yourclass import YourClass
> ```
>
> If this spelling causes local name clashes, then spell them
>
> ```
> import myclass
> import foo.bar.yourclass
> ```
>
> and use "myclass.MyClass" and "foo.bar.yourclass.YourClass".

There aren't really any 'rules' for this, just some pointers as mentioned above. If you are not obstructed by e.g. name clashing, you are free to do as you see fit.

However, as also mentioned in the link, you should keep in mind that

> Wildcard imports ( from  import * ) should be avoided, as they
>   make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing
>   both readers and many automated tools.

Answer (score 1):

Related to Tim Castelijns' answer, this is also an acceptable alternative:

```
from my_module import models as my_models
from their_module import models as their_models

class MyOtherModel(their_models.Foo):
    ...

class MyThirdModel(my_models.Bar):
    ...
```

That is to say, you are allowed to assign alternative names to imported modules. You have to keep readability in mind, though, so make sure it remains clear which module is referenced.

As an example, when deriving classes from another model, you may do so:

```
# in myproject.views
from shop.views.cart import CartDetails as ShopCartDetails

class CartDetails(ShopCartDetails):
    # my overridden methods
    ...
```

It gives you the opportunity to refer to the same class name when importing it in your `urls.py`:

```
# in myprojects.urls
from myproject.views import CartDetails

    ...
    url(r'^cart/$', CartDetails.as_view(), name='cart'),
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people would use the PEP8 style guide:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports